# iOS App crashes due to "function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Exploded>"

Tags: ios, swift

Crashlytics reported multiple crashes with the message:

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Exploded>
```

What does this exception mean at the first place?

Here's my code, the crash is reported in the "return resultSoFar" inside the closure.

```
private class func reduceMemberships(memberships: [HappeningMember]) -> (map: Dictionary<String, HappeningMember>, maxDateAsString: String?) {
    let maxDateAsString = Session.lastUpdatedAt
    let maxDateAsDouble = (maxDateAsString == nil) ? 0 : DateUtil.localDateFromIsoDateString(maxDateAsString!)!.timeIntervalSince1970
    let initialTuple = (map: Dictionary<String, HappeningMember>(), maxDateAsString: maxDateAsString, maxDateAsDouble: maxDateAsDouble )
    let reductionResult = memberships.reduce(initialTuple) {
        (var resultSoFar, membership) in
        let membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble = DateUtil.localDateFromIsoDateString(membership.updatedAt)!.timeIntervalSince1970
        resultSoFar.map[membership.happening._id] = membership
        resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble = max(membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble, resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble)
        resultSoFar.maxDateAsString = (resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble == membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble) ? membership.updatedAt : resultSoFar.maxDateAsString
        return resultSoFar // CRASHES HERE
    }
    return (reductionResult.map, reductionResult.maxDateAsString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you are returning from a completion handler. Try using a completion handler instead of a return, this will work with the asynchronous way this function works.

```
private class func reduceMemberships(memberships: [HappeningMember], completion: (map: Dictionary<String, HappeningMember>, maxDateAsString: String?)) {
    let maxDateAsString = Session.lastUpdatedAt
    let maxDateAsDouble = (maxDateAsString == nil) ? 0 : DateUtil.localDateFromIsoDateString(maxDateAsString!)!.timeIntervalSince1970
    let initialTuple = (map: Dictionary<String, HappeningMember>(), maxDateAsString: maxDateAsString, maxDateAsDouble: maxDateAsDouble )
    let reductionResult = memberships.reduce(initialTuple) {
        (var resultSoFar, membership) in
        let membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble = DateUtil.localDateFromIsoDateString(membership.updatedAt)!.timeIntervalSince1970
            resultSoFar.map[membership.happening._id] = membership
            resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble = max(membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble, resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble)
            resultSoFar.maxDateAsString = (resultSoFar.maxDateAsDouble == membershipUpdatedAtAsAdouble) ? membership.updatedAt : resultSoFar.maxDateAsString
        completion(map: resultSoFar.map, maxDateAsString: resultSoFar.maxDateAsString  )
    }
    completion(map: reductionResult.map, maxDateAsString: reductionResult.maxDateAsString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's the problem in returning from a completion handler? I tried it in a playground, and it's working as expected (the return version).

Comment: The problem is that completion handlers are asynchronous, this means that the completion handler is executed after that function has finished. So you can't return something from code that runs after a function has finished. Therefore you n need to use a completion handler instead